# Scala: how to specify type parameter bounds implying equality?

Tags: arrays, scala, types, parameters, type-bounds

Don't be put off by the long text, the points are quite trivial but require a bit of code to illustrate the problem. :-)

**The Setup:**

Say I would like to create a trait, here modeled as a `Converter` of some kind, that itself is generic but has a typed method `convert()` that returns an appropriately typed result object, say a `Container[T]`:

```
 trait Converter {
   def convert[T]( input: T ) : Container[T]
 } 
 trait Container[T]  // details don't matter
```

My question is about type constraints on methods, in particular for enforcing equality, and has two closely related parts.

**Part 1:** Say now that there was a specialized container type that was particularly suitable for array-based contents, like so:

```
 object Container {
   trait ForArrays[U] extends Container[Array[U]] 
 }
```

Given this possibility, I'd now like to specialize the Converter and in particular the return type of the `convert()` method, to the specialized `Container.ForArrays` type:

```
 object Converter {
   trait ForArrays extends Converter {
     // the following line is rubbish - how to do this right?
     def convert[E,T <: Array[E]]( input: T ) : Container.ForArrays[E]
   } 
 }
```

So that I can do something like this:

```
val converter = new Converter.ForArrays { ... }
val input = Array( 'A', 'B', 'C' )   
val converted : Container.ForArrays[Char] = converter.convert( input )
```

Basically I want Scala, if the type of converter is known to be `Converter.ForArrays`, to also infer the specialized return type of `convert[Char]()` as `Container.ForArrays[Char]`, i.e. the matching container type plus the array type of the input. Is this or something like it possible and if so, how do I do it? E.g. how do I specify the type parameters / bounds on convert() (what is provided is just a stand-in - I have no idea how to do this). Oh, and naturally so that it still overrides its super method, otherwise nothing is gained.

**Part 2:** As a fallback, should this not be possible, I could of course push the convert function down into the Array-focused variant, like so:

```
 trait Converter   // now pretty useless as a shared trait
 object Converter {
   trait ForValues extends Converter { 
     def convert[T]( input: T ) : Container[T] 
   }
   trait ForArrays extends Converter {
     def convert[E]( input: Array[E] ) : Container.ForArrays[E]
   } 
 }
```

OK. Now say I have an even more specialized `Converter.ForArrays.SetBased` that can internally use a set of elements of type E (the same as the 'input' array element type) to do some particular magic during the conversion. The set is now a parameter of the trait, however, like so:

```
 case class SetBased( set: Set[F] ) extends Converter.ForArrays {
   // the following line is also rubbish...
   def convert[E = F]( input: Array[E] ) : Container.ForArrays[E] = {...}
 }
```

Again, this is about the type parameters of the convert() method. The difficulty here is: how do I glue the type parameter of the class - `F` - to the type parameter of the method - `E` - such that the Scala compiler will only let the user call `convert()` with an array whose elements match the elements of the set? Example:

```
val set = Set( 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )
val converter = new Converter.ForArrays.SetBased( set )
val input = Array( 'A', 'B', 'C' )   
val converted : Container.ForArrays[Char] = converter.convert( input )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. For the same reason you can't narrow argument types or widen return types when overriding a method (but can narrow return type). Here is what you can do, however (for your fallback solution):

```
trait Converter {
  type Constraint[T]
} 

trait ForArrays extends Converter {
  def convert[E]( input: Array[E] )( implicit ev : Constraint[T] ) : Container.ForArrays[E]
}

case class SetBased[F](set: Set[F]) extends Converter {
   type Constraint[T] = T =:= F
   def convert[E]( input: Array[E] )( implicit ev : E =:= F ) = ...
}
```

Comment: OK, the point about not being able to narrow argument types seems to apply exactly to the first part, since it only permits `T`s that are also `Array[E]`. It makes sense to prevent a user holding a supertype `Converter` expecting T from inadvertently calling a method on a subtype that expects a narrower argument type and that could fail on it. Here, however, I just want the benefit of the narrowed return type. But the compiler cannot tell, and it's probably a rare edge case, so there's no point in making this work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `Container.ForArrays` is a subclass of `Container`, without this, `Converter.ForArrays.convert` won't match the signature of the overridden `Converter.convert`

Try writing it something like this:

```
object Converter {
  trait ForArrays extends Converter {
    def convert[E] (input: Array[E]): Container.ForArrays[E]
  } 
}
```

Regarding your fallback solution.  If two types are the same, then just use the same type param!

```
case class SetBased (set: Set[F]) extends Converter.ForArrays {
  def convert (input: Array[F]): Container.ForArrays[F] = {...}
}
```

Comment: As written, your convert in Converter.ForArrays does not override the one in Converter (different argument). Is it intended to be overloading?

Comment: Good point!  Actually, it doesn't need to override, depending on how you intend to use it.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, the idea was to have `Container.ForArrays` be a subclass of `Container`. That is also how I declared it in the example, but it was easy to overlook. I wanted the overriding `convert()` to specialize the return type of its overridden parent method.

Comment: @KevinWright Regarding the first suggestion: as didierd pointed out, it does not override the parent method; that was essentially my problem and the motivation for the post. The second suggestion is interesting and kind of obvious, so I will try that out. Unfortunately, the example was simplified a bit - in the real code, the situation is even worse since my set contains, say, Char but the convert method expects Array[Char], specializing a method expecting Array[Array[Char]] :-) Oh well.